# Lubuntu Temperature Monitor from Celcius to Fahrenheit

Tags: lubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu 15.04. I added the Temperature Monitor to the Panel so I can monitor the temperature of my laptop. However, It displays in Celsius and, being an American, I prefer Fahrenheit. Any way I can change that?

I tried right clicking it and going to "Temperature Monitor" Settings, but it only lets me edit the colors, sensor location and warning temperatures, also in Celsius.

Answer (score 0):

If you install `psensor`, in the settings you can select Celsius/Fahrenheit. I'm not sure how to get it for the monitor your using, but psensor has a panel icon, and a nice graph:
[image]
(The reason the temps are high is because KSP is running the background :P)